# How can I tell if the Content Caching feature is working correctly?

Tags: macos, network, command-line, system-settings

I enabled this on a Mac Mini which I use as a server with attached storage.

It's shows that it's "working" and my iMac finds it "healthy" however none of the large updates we've installed recently seem to be cached... I updated our family's 4 iPhones to iOS 17. Each of the iPhones is a different model.

I am thinking I haven't set it up properly but not sure. I presumed that no matter what device we use to initiate a download in the house (iPhones, AppleTV, iMac, MacBook Air, Mac Mini) they would all keep their downloaded software in the Content Cache on the Mac Mini.

```
2023-09-20 13:12:47.024 AssetCacheManagerUtil[2948:357455] Content caching status:
    Activated: true
    Active: true
    ActualCacheUsed: 7.54 GB
    CacheDetails: (4)
        iCloud: 6.47 GB
        iOS Software: 49.3 MB
        Mac Software: 926.3 MB
        Other: 5.18 GB
    CacheFree: 986.38 GB
    CacheLimit: 999 GB
    CacheStatus: OK
    CacheUsed: 12.62 GB
    Parents: (none)
    Peers: (none)
    PersonalCacheFree: 992.53 GB
    PersonalCacheLimit: 999 GB
    PersonalCacheUsed: 6.47 GB
    Port: 49268
    PrivateAddresses: (1)
        192.168.10.105
    PublicAddress: 73.xxx.xxx.xxx
    RegistrationStatus: 1
    RestrictedMedia: false
    ServerGUID: 4F60D46A-809D-43F8-B6B8-EB632AD5F6A0
    StartupStatus: OK
    TetheratorStatus: 0
    TotalBytesAreSince: 2023-09-20 12:58:51
    TotalBytesDropped: Zero KB
    TotalBytesImported: Zero KB
    TotalBytesReturnedToChildren: Zero KB
    TotalBytesReturnedToClients: Zero KB
    TotalBytesReturnedToPeers: Zero KB
    TotalBytesStoredFromOrigin: Zero KB
    TotalBytesStoredFromParents: Zero KB
    TotalBytesStoredFromPeers: Zero KB
```

```
john@iMac191 ~ % AssetCacheLocatorUtil
2023-09-20 13:16:06.833 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] AssetCacheLocatorUtil version 127, framework version 127
2023-09-20 13:16:06.834 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining public IP address...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.258 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] This computer's public IP address is 73.xxx.xxx.xxx.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.258 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] --- Information for system services:
2023-09-20 13:16:07.258 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Checking whether there might be content caches available...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.297 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] There might be content caches available.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.298 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding saved content caches supporting personal caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.299 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] There is no saved result.  (This is not an error.)
2023-09-20 13:16:07.299 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding saved content caches supporting personal caching and import...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.299 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] There is no saved result.  (This is not an error.)
2023-09-20 13:16:07.299 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding saved content caches supporting shared caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.300 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] There is no saved result.  (This is not an error.)
2023-09-20 13:16:07.300 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining saved configured public IP address ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.301 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No public IP address ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.301 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining saved favored server ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.301 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No favored server ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.301 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding refreshed content caches supporting personal caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.724 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:07.724 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding refreshed content caches supporting personal caching and import...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.724 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:07.724 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding refreshed content caches supporting shared caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] 192.168.10.105:49268, rank 2, not favored, healthy, guid 4F60D46A-809D-43F8-B6B8-EB632AD5F6A0, valid until 2023-09-20 14:16:07; supports personal caching: yes, and import: yes, shared caching: yes
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining refreshed configured public IP address ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No public IP address ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining refreshed favored server ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No favored server ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] --- Information for user 501 (results for other users may be different):
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Checking whether there might be content caches available...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] There might be content caches available.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.725 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding saved content caches supporting personal caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding saved content caches supporting personal caching and import...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding saved content caches supporting shared caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] 192.168.10.105:49268, rank 1, not favored, healthy, guid 4F60D46A-809D-43F8-B6B8-EB632AD5F6A0, valid until 2023-09-20 13:36:53; supports personal caching: yes, and import: yes, shared caching: yes
2023-09-20 13:16:07.726 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining saved configured public IP address ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.727 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No public IP address ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.727 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining saved favored server ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:07.727 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No favored server ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:07.727 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding refreshed content caches supporting personal caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding refreshed content caches supporting personal caching and import...
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Finding refreshed content caches supporting shared caching...
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Found 1 content cache
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] 192.168.10.105:49268, rank 2, not favored, healthy, guid 4F60D46A-809D-43F8-B6B8-EB632AD5F6A0, valid until 2023-09-20 14:16:08; supports personal caching: yes, and import: yes, shared caching: yes
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining refreshed configured public IP address ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No public IP address ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Determining refreshed favored server ranges...
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] No favored server ranges are configured.
2023-09-20 13:16:08.011 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] Testing all found content caches for reachability...
2023-09-20 13:16:08.015 AssetCacheLocatorUtil[68867:13310762] This computer is able to reach all of the above content caches.
```

Is my understanding of the caching being able to grab all the updates correct?

Comment: I'm wondering this myself from time to time. From the help page: "Content caching works only while your Mac is awake", should one read this as "If another device tries to download something while the caching Mac is sleeping, it will not use the cache"?